# CoreTextView & UIScrollview : Calculating window size

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am using [CoreTextView](https://github.com/giladno/UICoreTextView) on iOS to render an html file in a UIScrollview that is set up programmatically. As soon as the html file exceeds a certain length, the text no longer renders. It does not seem to be a problem with:

- Memory. NSLog displays the entire NSAttributedString no matter how long it is.
- A formatting error in the html file. I was able to render the entire file in pieces.

If I put in a very large height for the frame, same thing: **empty screen and no errors to troubleshoot.** I suspect that the issue has something to do with calculating file size and maybe... font line size? Stumped. Incidentally, if I enter a custom font, it is ignored and only the default Helvetica is displayed. Font SIZES, however, render correctly. Any help on getting the entire file to display would be much appreciated!

**My code:**

```
m_coreText = [[CoreTextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
m_coreText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
m_coreText.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);

NSString* html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"terms" ofType:@"html"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
m_coreText.attributedString = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithHTML:html renderer:^id<HTMLRenderer>(NSMutableDictionary* attributes) {
                                 CustomRenderer* renderer=[[CustomRenderer alloc] init];
                                 renderer.type=attributes[@"type"];
                                 renderer.size=CGSizeMake(16, 16);
                                 return renderer;
                             }];
m_coreText.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, [m_coreText sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, MAXFLOAT)].height);

UIScrollView* scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
scroll.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
scroll.contentSize=m_coreText.frame.size;
[scroll addSubview:m_coreText];
[self.view addSubview:scroll];
```

Comment: ps. The UIScrollview itself displays consistently in the iOs simulator, so this also is not the issue. (Sorry, was not able to add a screenshot because of StackOverflow limitations for new users).